# NPSP deleting values

Tags: delete, npsp

One of the records of our org was unexpectedly updated last month, and we saw on its history that the user **Nonprofit Success Pack** was responsible for that.

[image]

How can we discover the cause of the referred change? It's not supposed to uninstall NPSP, so we would like just to analyze the process that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Payed Amount a custom field?  NPSP provides user-defined rollup functionality, so you may have a user-defined rollup on that field.

Your best resource for NPSP support is the Salesforce Foundation's Power of Us Hub here: https://powerofus.force.com

You can login with your Salesforce ID and gain access to Chatter groups covering many aspects of the NPSP. Foundation staff, consultants and non-profit organizations are all participants in the groups.